# How do I read a SQLite database in Python on VSCode?

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

I have learned on CS50 that we can configure a Library to use SQLite database, on CS50 IDE, by doing this:

```py
from cs50 import SQL
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
```

Now I would like to do it in Visual Studio Code. But terminal returns me the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cs50'`.

What do I have to do to read a SQLite database on VSCode?

Comment: It is the same steps. Assuming you have python set up. It is like asking I can Drive ford but how do I drive GM.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

Comment: I understand. But the terminal is returning me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cs50'`. I edited my question including this.

Comment: that means that your interpreter can't find the package you are looking for. have you checked your environment to make sure the package is installed?

Comment: I would just use sqlite3 since it comes in python preinstalled. cs50 seems like geared for Computer Science teaching course only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem simply typing `pip install cs50` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

1. In VS Code, you have to install a [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) called python extension.
2. You have to download python interpreter for you OS and then let the VS know where is your installed python by clicking

> Ctrl + Shift + P

and then search for Python interpreter.

After setting up you can start coding in python importing any library, in your case CS50